# How to convert results returned from bigquery to Json format using Python?

Tags: python, json, google-bigquery

Using Python to select data from Bigquery public dataset, after getting the result need to print it in JSON format.How to convert the result to JSON ? Thanks!

Have tried `row[0]` but errors out.

```py
try:
    raw_results = query.rows[0]
    zipped_results = zip(field_names, raw_results)
    results = {x[0]: x[1] for x in zipped_results}
except IndexError:
    results = None

# from google.cloud import bigquery
# client = bigquery.Client()

query = """
    SELECT word, word_count
    FROM `bigquery-public-data.samples.shakespeare`
    WHERE corpus = @corpus
    AND word_count >= @min_word_count
    ORDER BY word_count DESC;
"""
query_params = [
    bigquery.ScalarQueryParameter("corpus", "STRING", "romeoandjuliet"),
    bigquery.ScalarQueryParameter("min_word_count", "INT64", 250),
]
job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig()
job_config.query_parameters = query_params
query_job = client.query(
    query,
    # Location must match that of the dataset(s) referenced in the 
    query.location="US",
    job_config=job_config,
)  # API request - starts the query

# Print the results
for row in query_job:
    print("{}: \t{}".format(row.word, row.word_count))
assert query_job.state == "DONE"
```

Answer (score 35):

There is no current method for automatic conversion, but there is a pretty simple manual method to convert to json:

```
records = [dict(row) for row in query_job]
json_obj = json.dumps(str(records))
```

Another option is to convert using pandas:

```
df = query_job.to_dataframe()
json_obj = df.to_json(orient='records')
```

Answer (score 7):

You can actually just have BigQuery produce JSON directly. Change your query like this:

```
query = """
SELECT TO_JSON_STRING(word, word_count) AS json
FROM `bigquery-public-data.samples.shakespeare`
WHERE corpus = @corpus
AND word_count >= @min_word_count
ORDER BY word_count DESC;
"""
```

Now the result will have a single column named `json` with JSON-formatted output.